# ObjectiveC/iphone: convert an array of dicts to an array composed of a certain attribute of each dict

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Looking for the most succinct way to convert an array of dicts to an array composed of a certain attribute of each dict. eg.

```
[ { name => 'Visa', value => 'VI' }, { name => 'Mastercard', value => 'MC' }]
=>
 ['Visa', 'Mastercard']
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
NSArray *nameArray = [yourArray valueForKey:@"name"];
```

> **valueForKey:** Returns an array containing the results of invoking
>   valueForKey: using key on each of the
>   receiver's objects.

Comment: awesome. I was looking at NSArray docs but missed that one. thank you!